# Showing $\sigma(X)= \{X^{-1}(B) , B \subset \mathscr{B}\}$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

> If $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n $ is any function. $\sigma(X)$ is the smallest sigma algebra generated by all the sets $X^{-1}(U)$, $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open.

I am confused as to how you show that:

> $\sigma(X)= \{X^{-1}(B) , B \in \mathscr{B}\}$
>
> With $\mathscr{B} =\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the Borel sigma algebra.

$\sigma(X)=\sigma(\{ X^{-1}(U), U\subset\mathbb{R}^n \})$ This is my starting point, I attempt to show this definition of $\sigma(X)$, and the one above, are both subset of each other i.e.

$\{X^{-1}(B) , B \in \mathscr{B}\} \supset \sigma(\{X^{-1}(U) , U \subset \mathbb{R}^n\}) $.

$\{X^{-1}(B) , B \in \mathscr{B}\} \subset \sigma(\{X^{-1}(U) , U \subset \mathbb{R}^n\}) $

According to my book it is sufficient to notice:

If $\mathscr{G} $ is any sigma field containing inverse images of Borel sets then $\mathscr{G} \supset \sigma(X)$

I am stuck here.

**((Added after an answer was posted.))**

> > Attempt.
>
> The topology $\mathscr{T}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by:
>
> 1. $\emptyset\in \mathscr{T}  $ and
>    $\mathbb{R}^n\in \mathscr{T}  $
> 2. Any union of elements in $\mathscr{T} $ is in $\mathscr{T}$
> 3. Any finite intersection of elements of $\mathscr{T}$ is in $\mathscr{T}$
>
> $\mathscr{T} \subseteq \mathscr{C}$ where $\mathscr{C} = \{ B \in \mathscr{B} : X^{-1}(B)\in\sigma(X)\}$

So for any element in $\mathscr{T}$ we have either the empty set, $\mathbb{R}^n$, any union of sets in $\mathscr{T}$, or any finite intersections of elements in $\mathscr{T}$.

If  $t \in  \{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}^n\}$, $X^{-1}(\emptyset)$ and $X^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are both in $\sigma(X)$, and obviously $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are in $\mathscr{B}$

If we have $t_1, t_2, \cdots \in \mathscr{T}$, then $\cup_{i\ge 0} t_i \in \mathscr{T}$. $t_i\in \mathscr{T}$ since $t_i$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which means that $t_i \in \mathscr{B}$ and that $X^{-1}(t_i) \in \sigma(X)$.  $X^{-1}(\cup_{i \ge 0}t_i) = \cup_{i\ge 0}X^{-1}(t_i)\in \sigma(X)$.

Similarly for any $t_1, t_2, \cdots \in \mathscr{T}$, with $\cap_{t \ge 0}t_i \in \mathscr{T}$, both are in $\mathscr{B}$, and $X^{-1}\in \sigma(X) \Rightarrow X^{-1}(\cap_{i\ge0} t_i) = \cap_{i \ge 0} X^{-1}(t_i) \in \sigma(X)$.

So if $t \in \mathscr{T}$ then $t \in \mathscr{C}$.

> $\mathscr{C} $ is a sigma algebra.

$\emptyset \in \mathscr{C}$

if $C \in \mathscr{C}$ then $C^c \in \mathscr{B}$ and $X^{-1}(C) \in \sigma(X)$ so $(X^{-1}(C))^c = X^{-1}(C^c) \in \sigma(X)$, so $C^c \in \mathscr{C}$.

If $\{C_i\}$ are in $\mathscr{C}$ then $\cup_{i\ge 0}(C_i)\in\mathscr{B}$ and $\cup_{i\ge0}X^{-1}(C_i) = X^{-1}( \cup_{i\ge0}C_i ) \in \sigma(X) $

> Hence, $\mathscr{C}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathscr{T}$ hence $\mathscr{C} \subset \mathscr{B}$, the smallest sigma algebra containing $\mathscr{T}$, so $\mathscr{C}=\mathscr{B}$.

$$ \{ B\in\mathscr{B}\} = \{ B\in\mathscr{B} : X^{-1}(B) \in \sigma(X) \}$$

$$ X^{-1}(B) \in \sigma(X) \forall B\in\mathscr{B}$$

$$ X^{-1}(B) \in \sigma\{X^{-1}(U), U \subset \mathbb{R}^n, \text{open} \} \forall B\in\mathscr{B} $$

$$ \{X^{-1}(B) : B \in \mathscr{B} \} = \sigma(\{ X^{-1}(U) : U \subset \mathbb{R}^n, \text{open} \}) $$

Comment: Note that $\sigma(X)= \{X^{-1}(B) , B \in\mathscr{B}\}$ (hence you are confusing $\subset$ and $\in$) and that nobody denotes by $\sigma(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the Borel sigma-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (one rather uses $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$).

Comment: Thanks I have changed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathscr C=\{B\in\mathscr B\mid X^{-1}(B)\in\sigma(X)\}$, where $\mathscr B$ is the Borel sigma-algebra on $\mathbb R^n$. By definition, $\mathscr C\subseteq\mathscr B$, and you know that $\mathscr T\subseteq\mathscr C$, where $\mathscr T$ is the *topology* on $\mathbb R^n$, that is, the collection of open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$. Furthermore, $\mathscr C$ is a sigma-algebra (*can you prove this?*), and $\mathscr B$ is the sigma-algebra generated by $\mathscr T$. Thus...

Comment: Was the edit to my question correct?